# Django: Cannot assign "u'1'": "Likes.post" must be a "Post" instance

Tags: python, django

I have model called Likes:
**model** : Likes:

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return post

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**view** like:

```
def like(request,post_id = None):
    like = Likes.objects.create(post=post_id,user_id=request.session['user_id'])

    try:
        like.save()
    except like.DoesNotExist:
        cannot = "true"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cannot),content_type="application/json")
    cannot = "false"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cannot),content_type="application/json")
```

my **html** is:

[like](/polls/likes/1/)

when i click like i am getting this error

```
Cannot assign "u'1'": "Likes.post" must be a "Post" instance.
```

I am new to django. Please help me out with this error. or am i doing wrong with associations?

Comment: Calling `save()` shouldn't raise `DoesNotExist`, so it doesn't make sense to catch that exception there. When you call `create()`, the like will be saved to the database, so you don't actually need that block where you call `save()` at all.

Comment: It would be better to have  `user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. The `like.user` is the related `user` object, and `like.user_id` is the id of the related user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you should assign a `Post` instance to the `post` field, but you are trying to assign the id `'1'` instead.

You can either fetch the `post` from the database first:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
Likes.objects.create(post=post, user_id=request.session['user_id'])
```

Or you can assign the id directly to `post_id`:

```
Likes.objects.create(post_id=post_id, user_id=request.session['user_id'])
```

Fetching the post is probably better because it checks that the `post_id` refers to a valid post. The `get_object_or_404` shortcut will return a 404 error page if the post with that id is not found.

As an aside, it's easier to get the user from `request.user` if you are using Django's authentication:

```
Likes.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user)
```

Comment: i am familiar with ruby on rails. but i am completly new to django. so i don't know how to edit my table which was migrated already. either crispy answer or suggestion of an article about django migration would be great help @Alasdair

Comment: That sounds like a separate question - you don't need to edit your table, just change the lines in the view.

Comment: And i am not using Django's Authentication, How can i get user id assigned from my session? @Alasdair

Comment: You really should use [Django's authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/#user-authentication-in-django). It's more secure that rolling your own system, and you'll find it easier to get help if you get stuck. I can't help if you are doing something custom using `request.session`.

Comment: How can i manually enter `ForeignKey` of  likes table with user table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.